# Form validations with ngModel and ngModelOption in angular 8

Tags: angular, ngmodel, angular2-form-validation

I'm using angular 8 with formGroup and formController for validation which works great through reactive as well as template-driven form.
However, I was trying to use "ngModel" in angular 8 with "ngModelOptions" attributes (it's a dynamically generated fields). It shows field level validations correctly with "required" attribute, but I'm unable prevent button click or disable the "button" on error validation state. A sample code is given below:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" #form1="ngForm">
 <!-- few formControlName fields here -->
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="firstname" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [placeholder]="First name" required />
   <mat-error>This field is <strong>required</strong></mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="lastname" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [placeholder]="Last name" required />
   <mat-error>This field is <strong>required</strong></mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-button [disabled]="!(form1.form.valid)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Submit button never disabled in spite of the blank first name and last name fields. I understand When you mark it as standalone: true this will not happen (it will not be added to the FormGroup).
But is there any workaround or other approaches where I can achieve the ngModel validations to restrict the form submission on the button?

Comment: Would you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270564/dividing-a-form-into-multiple-components-with-validation/43277336

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz example?

Comment: Try this `[disabled]="!form1.form.valid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put in the same tag

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" #form1="ngForm">
```

"form1" is myForm, and "firstName" and "lastName" don't belong to myForm.

if you use

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

your input don't belong to any form.

You can add in your inputs #firstnameID="ngModel" and #lastnameID="ngModel" and ask about firstnameID.valid  and lastnameID.valid

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" #form1="ngForm">
 <!-- few formControlName fields here -->
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="firstname" 
        #firstnameID="ngModel"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
        placeholder="First name" required />
   <mat-error>This field is <strong>required</strong></mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="lastname" 
       #lastnameID="ngModel"
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
       placeholder="Last name" required />
   <mat-error>This field is <strong>required</strong></mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-button [disabled]="!(myForm.valid) ||
                               !firstnameID.valid ||
                               !lastnameID.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

NOTE: I suppose it's not the answer you expect but it's in this way

Comment: Template-Driven Form validation follows this pattern of assigning a template variable to input bind with ngModel and that reference can be utilize to add validations (valid, pristine etc).

Comment: This looks a good work around considering my requirements to have both fonrControlName as well as ngModelOptions. Thanks!

Comment: How do you handle ngFor ? For instance a list of contacts for an address.  The button must be enabled only if all the controls in the array are valid