Angular Parent Form + childForm
i got a question i havent found an answer too and i was curious if one of you came across this.
Imagine having a ParentForm and a ChildForm. Child and Parent are each one Angular Component.
parentForm: FormControl = new FormBuilder.group({})

childForm: FormControl = new FormBuilder.group({
 checkbox: false,
})

now if i want to add the childForm to the parentForm to connect them, i would do:
@(ViewChild)(ChildComponent) = childComponent;

ngAfterViewInit(): {
   this.parentForm.addControl('childFormName', this.childComponent.childForm)
}

This whole action would make the ParentForm look like this:
parentForm: {
 childFormName: {
  checkbox: false
 }
}

I dont want this, i would like to not have to give the added form an extra name, and would want to have it look like this:
parentForm: {
  checkbox: false
}

Has anyone every ecountered a usecase for this?
thanks for the help in advance

Hi, Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270564/dividing-a-form-into-multiple-components-with-validation

First I would clone the child form, since I do not want the updates on the child form to propagate to the parent. Then simply using object de-structuring add the controls to the parent form.
I am using cloneDeep from lodash for cloning since its the most reliable method to create a deep clone ( my preference ).
ngOnInit() {
  const cloneChildForm = cloneDeep(this.childForm);
  this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
    ...this.parentForm.controls,
    ...cloneChildForm.controls,
  });

  console.log(this.parentForm);
}

Stackblitz Demo

Im a little embarrased. That is the most simple solution i didnt think of. Thank you.
you dont acutally need the ...this.parentForm and i want the event from the child.
But the rest of your solution is exactly what i want. Thanks!
